# How to put each question of ONE form in 3 different HTML files?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form that consists of 3 questions and inputs where the user writes answers. When one finishes and pushes the submit button, it sends a letter to the organization with the inserted info. Right now the whole form is in one html file. I want to split this form into 3 different html files. Each question will have its own html file, BUT the submit button in the last 3rd html file will gather info just like it does now.

My HTML code:

```
<form action="mailto:example@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
  Comment:<br>
  <input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

P.S. I will add "anchors" to jump from one question to the next. My only problem is how to submit in the 3rd html file all the info that were entered in all three files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an actual `submit` for the first few (use a button or an anchor...etc), and use JavaScript to switch between questions (simply hide and show questions based on which one they're on).

On the last question, use the actual `submit` button, and because they're all on the same form, all the data will be submitted.